# how to call a function using a jquery .mouseleave event

Tags: jquery, function, events

I have a function:

```
function saveNotes(i)
{ 
    localStorage.setItem("textCopy" + i, $("#container_" + i).val());
}
```

and i want to call it on `.mouseleave` in 3 cases:

```
$("#container_1").mouseleave(saveNotes(1));
$("#container_2").mouseleave(saveNotes(2));
$("#container_3").mouseleave(saveNotes(3));
```

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current logic is that you immediately call the `saveNotes` function and set it's return value to be used as the event handler. Clearly this isn't quite right.

To fix this you could wrap the function calls in an anonymous function, like this:

```
$("#container_1").mouseleave(function() { saveNotes(1); });
$("#container_2").mouseleave(function() { saveNotes(2); });
$("#container_3").mouseleave(function() { saveNotes(3); });
```

However this isn't very DRY and will be pain to maintain. You can improve that by using a common class on all the `#container_N` elements along with a `data` attribute to store the custom meta data on the element. Try this:

```js
$(".container").mouseleave(function() {
  saveNotes($(this).data('foo'));
});

function saveNotes(i) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-foo="1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="container" data-foo="2">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="container" data-foo="3">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

Using a single function and getting the number from the `id`:

```
$("#container_1, #container_2, #container_3").mouseleave(function() {
    saveNotes(parseInt(this.id.split("_")[1]));
});
```

Inline functions:

```
$("#container_1").mouseleave(() => saveNotes(1));
$("#container_2").mouseleave(() => saveNotes(2));
$("#container_3").mouseleave(() => saveNotes(3));
```

`bind` (basically the same as inline functions):

```
$("#container_1").mouseleave(saveNotes.bind(null, 1));
$("#container_2").mouseleave(saveNotes.bind(null, 2));
$("#container_3").mouseleave(saveNotes.bind(null, 3));
```

Either of those last two can be used in a loop, if that's appropriate in your case:

```
// NOTE: Important to use `let`, not `var`, and declare it in the `for`!
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    $("#container_" + i).mouseleave(() => saveNotes(i));
}
```

or

```
// Here `let`/`var` doesn't matter
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    $("#container_" + i).mouseleave(saveNotes.bind(null, i));
}
```

Comment: just for general knowledge,   ```mouseleave``` is when the object is unhovered, right? bc when I press the button to activate the function its works, but when I unhovere the function won't work.

Comment: @avivgood3 - Yes, `mouseleave` is fired at the element when the mouse moves from within it to outside it.

Comment: @avivgood3 - It's impossible to say without a [mcve]. But note that both Rory and I have answered the question you actually asked. If you have a *different* question ("okay, but why doesn't it work in this specific case?"), that's a *different* question.